# I am unable to login to admin-dashboard application in WSO2 API manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I'm unable to login to admin dashboard in WSO2 API manager. I got an error "Unable to log you in! Login Failed "

API Manager is configured with LDAP read only primary user store. Our LDAP do not have groups and roles are not red from LDAP.

Additionally API Manager is configured to work with MySQL DB and WSO2 IS as key manager. But I think this is not a reason of such behavior.

If I configure API Manager with a standard user store (without any changes to user-mgt.xml) login to admin-dashboard works OK.

Comment: This problem was resolved. In file /repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/admin-dashboard/conf/site.json I changed "admin" role name to **'"Internal/admin":  "allowedRole":"Internal/admin",
"allowedRoles":"Internal/admin,Internal/subscriber"**, Now I can connect to admin-dashboard. I think Internal is necessary because of ReadOnly LDAP user store without groups.

Comment: Add this as answer to the question and accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem was resolved.

In file

```
/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/admin-dashboard/conf/site.json
```

I changed "admin" role name to '"Internal/admin":

```
"allowedRole":"Internal/admin",

"allowedRoles":"Internal/admin,Internal/subscriber"
```

Now I can connect to admin-dashboard. I think Internal is necessary because of ReadOnly LDAP user store without groups.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer did solve the issue. However, **the correct path/file is actually**:

```
/repository/deployment/server/jaggeryapps/admin-dashboard/**site/**conf/site.json
```

The original post missed "site" before "conf" folder, in case anyone is wondering.

At least this applies to wso2 am 1.10.0