# I installed WSO2 AM(API Manager) 1.10.0 and used the user-mgt.xml from working AM 1.9.0, but now I cannot login to carbon admin UI

Tags: ldap, wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-manager

I installed WSO2 AM(API Manager) 1.10.0 and used the user-mgt.xml from working AM 1.9.0, but now I cannot login to carbon admin UI.

API Manager is configured with LDAP read only primary user store.

Additionally API Manager is configured to work with default H2. But I think this is not a reason.

If I configure API Manager with a standard user store (without any changes to user-mgt.xml, i.e. without adding readOnlyLdap config and removing default JDBC UserStoreManager), login to admin-dashboard works OK.

I got the warning message from wso2carbon.log:

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-07-03 05:55:54,731]  WARN {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil} -  Failed Administrator login attempt 'admin[-1234]' at [2016-07-03 05:55:54,730+0000] {org.wso2.carbon.core.services.util.CarbonAuthenticationUtil}
```

I made the changes as suggested per [I am unable to login to admin-dashboard application in WSO2 API manager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36057317/i-am-unable-to-login-to-admin-dashboard-application-in-wso2-api-manager) , unfortunately that solution did not work for me.

Basically I installed brand new WSO2 am 1.10.0, with default settings, all works fine, until I changed user-mtg.xml to enable LDAP, I cannot login to carbon/admin UI anymore. So LDAP does not work out of the box with wso2 am 1.10.0? I followed the instructions related to LDAP set up, but it just did not work.

The strange thing is, LDAP works with am 1.9.0. So any difference in setting up LDAP between version 1.10.0 and 1.9.0?

UPDATE:

For the moment, I gave up integarting LDAP with wso2 am 1.10.0. I moved to SAML2. But keep the question open in case someone has worked out of this with a solution, or this might help others. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of the GetAllRolesOfUserEnabled property under AuthorizationManager in user-mgt.xml?

```
<AuthorizationManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager">
            <Property name="AdminRoleManagementPermissions">/permission</Property>
            <Property name="AuthorizationCacheEnabled">true</Property>
            <Property name="GetAllRolesOfUserEnabled">false</Property>
        </AuthorizationManager>
```

That property is not part of the 1.9 config and in 1.10 the default config has this set to false and we were seeing similar login issues.  Setting this to true resolved this issue for us.

Joe

Comment: Thanks for the reply. This was set to false explicitly as was suggested from another online source:  <Property name="GetAllRolesOfUserEnabled">false</Property> . I will set that to true and update here.

Comment: I tested with that parameter set to "true". Unfortunately this did not work for us. I also re-tested with a brand new wso2 am 1.10.0 and enabled ldap with this parameter set to true and some necessry changes in carbon.xml(so user name can be in email format). Still, I cannot login using LDAP credentials, or default admin credentials. Something is missing from WSO2 documentation when upgrade wso2 am 1.9.0 to 1.10.0 with LDAP enabled. (My 1.9.0 with LDAP works perfectly. I just cannot upgrade it with LDAP!)

Comment: Ok, not sure I have any other good ideas on this one.  Our configuration ended up slightly different than yours as we use LDAP as our secondary user store as opposed to the primary.  Given you have had no issues in previous versions I do not see how this could help but the only other suggestions I would have would be playing around with the value of UserNameAttribute in your UserStoreManager because we had to alter the default config to make that work for us.  Sorry I could not be more help...Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I can provide following hints.

1. Since you haven't mentioned about the master-datasources.xml, I doubt the following. Do you have a external userstore database used in 1.9.0? If so, have you pointed 1.10.0 to the same database?
2. Log doesn't clearly say whether it failed due to authentication or authorization error. To find this out, you need to enable debug logs for the package org.wso2.carbon.user.core. This can be done in the repository/conf/log4j.properties file and needs a restart. Then, when your next login attemp fails, it will show you more details.

Comment: 1. Yes, I pointed to the brand new databases for wso am 1.10.0, as the API data cannot be ported from 1.9.0 anyway.  2. I will take a look at next time. But I am currently switching to saml2 - BTW, it also has its own issues. Anyway thanks for the help.

Comment: I think you still need to point it to the old userstore database. Reason is, although your users and roles are in your LDAP, permissions are stored in the userstore database. I believe this is the reason for the failure. You will be able to find it out by enabling debug logs.

Comment: I thought the migration script should have handled this. This makes me really concerned to use wso2 products: the migration/upgrade process is painful, even for very close versions such as from wso2 am 1.9.0 to 1.10.0. Thanks for the update anyway.

Comment: I initially pointed to old database but it threw quite a few errors. Later I started from brand new 1.10.0 installation.